# Sort ObservableCollection<T> without creating new list

Tags: vb.net, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection(Of T) and I'm currently trying to figure out a way to sort the list, without having to create a new one. I use the following code to do this, the ObservableCollection is made up of Userprincipal information.

```
Dim SortedList2 = ChooseUserObservableCollection.OrderBy(Function(o) o.UserPrin.DisplayName).ThenBy(Function(o) o.UserPrin.DistinguishedName).ToList()
```

This works fine, but again, I have to create a new variable, when I would just like to sort the list as it stands. This list is used as an item-source, so not reloading it would be the goal.

Could somebody inform me of a better approach to this?

Answer (score 1):

The [CollectionViewSource Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource?view=netframework-4.8) is designed to provide sorting and filtering capabilities for a source collection.

You can configure it something like shown below:

```
Dim viewSource As New CollectionViewSource
Dim init As ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize = viewSource
init.BeginInit()
viewSource.View.SortDescriptions.Add((New ComponentModel.SortDescription("DisplayName", ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)))
viewSource.View.SortDescriptions.Add((New ComponentModel.SortDescription("DistinguishedName", ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)))
viewSource.Source = ChooseUserObservableCollection
init.EndInit()
```

Then you would assign the `CollectionViewSource .View` to the `ItemsSource` property of your UI control.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ToList() it; just pass it away to whatever will enumerate it:

```
Return ChooseUserObservableCollection.OrderBy(Function(o) o.UserPrin.DisplayName).ThenBy(Function(o) o.UserPrin.DistinguishedName)
```

Bear in mind that it is at the point of enumeration that the Linq query will run and the list will be sorted, rather than the point at which OrderBy is called. If it's mandatory that the ordering happen very soon after it's called then you'll need to ToList() it (or similar)..

Comment: This doesn't seem to be actually sorting the data, at least on the itemssource side. I set this to a ICollectionView, and then allow that to be the itesmsource of the listbox. Knowing this, would I need to do it any different?

Comment: Are you saying that it does sort when you ToList() and doesn't when you don't? If it never sorts, you should ask a new question as the scope of the current question does not include failure to sort

Comment: In order to sort you need to enumerate. ToList will keep it enumerated and not enumerate again, unless you do something else to it. It will also keep it sorted.

Comment: @CaiusJard It sorts, just breaks the binding to the item-source. I'll reform the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the additional variable is your best bet. In this simple example,

```vb
Dim a = {6, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1}.OrderBy(Function(i) i Mod 2).ThenBy(Function(i) i)
Console.WriteLine(a.First())
Console.WriteLine(a.Last())
```

`a` will be enumerated twice.

You can prevent that by calling `ToList()` on the original variable to enumerate it immediately

```vb
Dim a = {6, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1}.OrderBy(Function(i) i Mod 2).ThenBy(Function(i) i).ToList()
Console.WriteLine(a.First())
Console.WriteLine(a.Last())
```

or using a second variable

```vb
Dim a = {6, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1}.OrderBy(Function(i) i Mod 2).ThenBy(Function(i) i)
Dim b = a.ToList()
Console.WriteLine(b.First())
Console.WriteLine(b.Last())
```

Of course, with the second variable, accessing `a` again later can cause it to be enumerated again.

If it's time consuming to query, then there are considerations you need to make in your application of which I don't know enough about.